# How to display multiple selection and single selection in HTML select form base on previous dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, dropdown

I have two dropdown menu in my HTML, Am trying to work a way around it that when I select **"Multiple"** in the first dropdown the second dropdown can be multiple="multiple" and when I select **Single** on the first dropdown the second dropdown can be set to single and not multiple and finally when I select **Others** the second dropdown will be single too. Below is my code:

```html
<!------------------------- First Dropdown -------------------------->
<div class="ss-custom-select">
  <select class="full-width" id="blocation" name="blocation">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the number of physical location</option>

    <option value="One">Single</option>
    <option value="Multiple">Multiple</option>
    <option value="Online">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!------------------------- Second Dropdown -------------------------->
<div class="ss-custom-select">
  <select class="full-width" id="subtype" name="subtype[]" multiple="multiple">

    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the subtype of business</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

Note I call .change() on load

```js
$("#blocation").on("change",function() {
  $("#subtype").prop("multiple",this.value==="Multiple")
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------------------------- First Dropdown -------------------------->
<div class="ss-custom-select">
  <select class="full-width" id="blocation" name="blocation">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the number of physical location</option>

    <option value="One">Single</option>
    <option value="Multiple">Multiple</option>
    <option value="Online">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!------------------------- Second Dropdown -------------------------->
<div class="ss-custom-select">
  <select class="full-width" id="subtype" name="subtype[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the subtype of business</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">One</option>
    <option value="3">One</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, this is not working it shows the multiple all through even when I tried to choose single and others.

Comment: Works in Chrome, Edge and Firefox